# add div class inside appended iFrame with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, iframe, coffeescript

im creating and adding an iFrame as the following:

```
$("#iframe").append setIframe(gon.user_appointments_url + "/" + calEvent.id + "/edit", 630)

setIframe = (srcAttribute, height) ->
  ifrm = document.createElement("IFRAME")
  ifrm.setAttribute "src", srcAttribute
  ifrm.style.width = 100 + "%"
  ifrm.style.height = height + "px"
  return ifrm
```

After this, that works fine, i pretend to add a class that will set the header's color on the iFrame, depending on the element's "status". So i call the following function:

```
setHeaderBgColor(getDivClassFromStatus(jsEvent.status))

setHeaderBgColor = (header_div_class) ->
  $("iframe").contents().find("#appointments-form-header").addClass header_div_class
```

But this doesnt work. I never seem to get to "#appointments-form-header" and dont find the way to do it.

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are all the arrows pointing to, I keep looking to the right, but all I see is my scrollbar ?

Comment: Hi @adeneo, arrows are just coffeescript syntaxis for function. Just read it as a regular .js function() {

Comment: I was just joking! Is the iFrame loading from the same domain, port etc. and did you wait for it to load before trying to access the elements inside.

Comment: the loading thing might be.. I'll take a look. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#iframe").append setIframe(gon.user_appointments_url + "/" + calEvent.id + "/edit", 630)

setIframe = (srcAttribute, height) ->
  ifrm = document.createElement("IFRAME")
  ifrm.setAttribute "src", srcAttribute
  ifrm.style.width = 100 + "%"
  ifrm.style.height = height + "px"
  ifrm.onload = setContent
  return ifrm

  setHeaderBgColor = (header_div_class) ->
    $("#iframe").contents().find("#appointments-form-header").addClass header_div_class

  setContent() -> 
    setHeaderBgColor(getDivClassFromStatus(jsEvent.status))
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: No console error, but this is undefined: $("iframe").contents().find("#appointments-form-header").attr('class')

Comment: $("#iframe") <> $("iframe")

Comment: Shouldn't that line be formatted in CoffeeScript too?

Comment: Have you tried console.log($("#iframe").contents());

Comment: just now, console.log($("#iframe").contents()) is undefined. Im trying on chrome's console so format should be js..